# Learn Python the Hard Way ex33 - Put while-loop in function

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to put a while-loop in a function and then execute the function. The while loop on its own is fine, but when I put it in a function, it repeats to infinity.

```
x = int(raw_input("> "))

def function1(x):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    while i < x:                            
        print "At the top i is %d" % i      
        numbers.append(i)                   
        i += 1                          
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers      
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i   

function1(x)
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is properly indented

Answer (score 0):

In python indentation is very important. When starting a function everything inside that function must be indented, just like how you did with your `while` loop.

```
x = int(raw_input("> "))

def function1(x):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    while i < x:                            
        print "At the top i is %d" % i      
        numbers.append(i)                   
        i += 1                          
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers      
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i   

function1(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try run it as written, it doesn't run because of indentation.

When I indent it as follows:

```
x = int(raw_input("> "))

def function1(x):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    while i < x:                            
        print "At the top i is %d" % i      
        numbers.append(i)                           
        i += 1                          
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers      
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i   

function1(x)
```

It runs perfectly fine (I tested by giving some small integers as input). Make sure your indentation is correct, this is very very important in Python.

A helpful rule of thumb for when you're learning is that whenever you end a line in a colon (`:`) (e.g. `if` statements, functions declarations, `while` loops) you should probably be indenting the next block of code.

Comment: Sorry, I originally typed in my code incorrectly (learning StackO formatting still). But anyways, I edited how the code looks; I had proper indentation. 

For some reason, TextWrangler was picking up the end of my while-loop block after the first line with 'print "At the top i...."etc. So I indented 'numbers.append(i) below that line, and the code ran perfectly fine. 

But shouldn't this be an indentation error? Is there something wrong with my text editor?

Comment: If you can show me how you had it indented I can tell you, but it's not very clear what you mean by "indented 'numbers.append(i) below that line". Did you indent to the same level as the line above it?

Comment: No, for some reason the script wanted me to indent the 'numbers.append() line 4 more spaces below the first line asking telling the loop to 'print'. I indented the rest of the block 4 more spaces below the 'print' line and the script ran. I'm pretty sure thats an indentation error, but it worked somehow.

Comment: just to be clear, the rest block after `print` was indented _more_ than the print statement? As in, not how I have it indented?

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me when indented properly per ltd9938's answer. Does it work for you when properly indented, if not what is the exact output you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, I originally typed in my code incorrectly (learning StackO formatting still). But anyways, I edited how the code looks; I had proper indentation. 

For some reason, TextWrangler was picking up the end of my while-loop block after the first line with 'print "At the top i...."etc. So I indented 'numbers.append(i) below that line, and the code ran perfectly fine. 

But shouldn't this be an indentation error? Is there something wrong with my text editor?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by indented 'numbers.append(i) below that line?

Answer (score 0):

Python uses tabs as a delimiter. Make sure you indent.